# Raise exception if condition is true in one-line?

Tags: python

I have a lot of assert statements I use to validate input data and state of the program. ie :

```py
assert all((i.children is not None for i in items)), "Someone has no children."
```

I would like to use the same syntax but using specific Exception, ie:

```py
if any((i.children is None for i in items)):
  raise NoChildrenException("Someone has no children.")
```

Is there a one line syntax to achieve the same?
I tried :

```py
if any((i.children is None for i in items)): raise NoChildrenException("Someone has no children.")
```

but that's not PEP8 valid.

or

```py
def raise_if(condition, clazz, *args):
  if condition:
    raise(clazz(*args))


raise_if(any((i.children is None for i in items)), NoChildrenException, "Someone has no children.")
```

but that's a bit ugly.

**UPDATE**:

Thanks @Thomas. I fixed the examples in the problem description.
I think the closest to what I want to achieve is this one (based on @puchal's answer).

```py
def raise_exc(exc):
    raise exc

all((i.children is not None for i in items) or raise_exc(NoChildrenException("Someone has no children."))
```

I haven't thought about using `or` in this way.

Comment: Not if you want to 100% stick with PEP8... IMHO a 2-line `if` is fine. You can surely put everything on one line if the condition and exception is short enough (Keep in mind that PEP8's requirement of 79-char lines is "bogus", not worth following in 2019 with our monitors, 100--120 chars per line can be fine once in a while and the newest PEP8 texts say as much).

Comment: Don't use `assert` for validation; it's a debugging tool that can be turned off at run time.

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta, I don't agree with you that the line length limit is "bogus". Did you actually read PEP-8? They provide good reasons to obey this rule, which are still valid in 2019. For exampe: "_Limiting the required editor window width makes it possible to have several files open side-by-side, and works well when using code review tools that present the two versions in adjacent columns._"  I do agree with you that a 2-line `if` is fine. Trying to put everything on one line is bogus, IMHO ;-)

Comment: @chepner Yes I figured it out, that's why I would like to change them.

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta PEP8 is complaining that the second statement after : should be on another line, not complaining about line length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do it ellegantly.

I think the closest way to achieve it would be:

```py
def raise_exc(clazz, msg=""):
    raise clazz(msg)

all((i.children is not None for i in items)) or raise_exc(NoChildrenException, 'message')
```

Answer (score 3):

Currently there is no way to do this that is also valid PEP8.

It doesn't get more pythonic than this:

```py
if any(i.children is None for i in items):
    raise NoChildrenException("Someone has no children.")
```

Note you have an error in your problem description - you have to negate the condition in your second code example. You can get rid of the two `not` by using `any()` like shown above.

Answer (score 0):

The "correct" way to do this is without `assert` at all.

```
if any(i.children is None for i in items):
    raise ValueError("Someone has no children")  # Or whatever exception you feel is appropriate
```

In Python 3.8, you can capture *which* item had no children in the same line.

```
if any((childless:=i).children is None for i in items):
    raise ValueError("%r is childless" % (childless,))
```

(The assignment expression operator `:=` creates a variable in the scope where the generator expression is defined, not one local to the generator expression itself.)

Answer (score 0):

Your second snippet is the most pythonic IMHO.

When I have to add a lot of validation rules I usually do something like this:

```
checks = {
    lambda items: any(i.children is None for i in items): NoChildrenException("Someone has no children."),
    lambda items: any(i.children.age >= 18 for i in items): AdultChildrenException("Someone has an adult children."),
    lambda items: not bool(items): NoItemsException("No items given."),
}

for condition, exc in checks.items():
    if condition(items):
        raise exc
```

Moving all the checks (eventually having bigger functions instead of lambdas) in a separate .py file "validations.py".